# jQuery script works in Wordpress preview mode only. Javascript portion seems to work

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to load a jQuery script onto my Wordpress site. The script works in preview mode however when I go to the normal published page as a visitor, it doesn't run properly. I know the script is being run because I a placed window.alert in the script to test it and it runs properly. I can also see the script being applied in the page source code. I hope you can help me out! Thank you!

Comment: You're going to need to provide far more information that what you have already. Errors and some code would be a start.

Comment: If it helps this is the page [link](http://www2.milani.ca/reviews-campaign/). I'm not sure what I'm looking for. It's supposed to unhide one of a list of hidden elements and then unhide a different element when the select input is changed.

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess that Wordpress is probably already loading a version of JQuery on your site. I just went to a Wordpress site and I noticed that Wordpress is loading Jquery version 1.12.4.  If you're having trouble with it then try debugging using your online debugger.  In Chrome you can right click on the page and choose Inspect at the bottom of the Dialog.  If you have trouble finding the code the try putting a console command like the following into your javascript (ie JQuery) code.

```
console.log("flag");
```

And then go to the console and look for 'flag' and on the extreme right of the console you will have a link which will take you to the code.

Comment: I gave it a try but I can't see any problems for this particular script.